# Unresolved import 'keyboard'

Tags: python, python-3.x, visual-studio, pip

I install keyboard with `pip install keyboard` and visual studio succesfully installed it but visual studio gives error as:

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'keyboard'

Comment: Are you using the right environment?

Comment: I dont know visual studio good.Can you explain me how can ı know using right environment?

Comment: Yes of course, i'll explain in an answer.

Answer (score 0):

All packages are installed in your selected environment, so you need to select that environment to use its packages.
The current environment is shown in the left-bottom corner of your window, something like this: `Python 3.7.3 64-bit`

You can change and select your environment by using Command Palette `(Ctrl+Shift+P)`, type `Python: Select Interpreter` in the palette to see defined environments.

You can list all packages in an environment by using the following commands based on the package manager:

- `pip list`
- `conda list`

Comment: I use pip list and keyboard is in there but it gives error again. I am using python 3.8 and I tried to use 3.7 but nothing changes it gives error.

Comment: What you can do create a separate environment using conda with python version and install what ever is your requirement and use that environment